# Page reload not working when the page was called by AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, reload

Let's say this is my AJAX

```
function call_page(id)
{   
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "call_me.php",
          data: "id=" + id,
          success: function(msg){ }                 
     });   
}
```

call_me.php was successfully called.

Let's say this is my call_me.php content

```
<?php

$var = $_POST['id'];

if(empty($var))
{
    header("location: call_me.php?id=101");
}
else
{
    do something...
}

?>
```

Assuming that the first condition 'if(empty($var))' is always satisfied.
The page must reload and the go to the else statement.
But this is not happening. I guess the page isn't reloading.

How can I correct this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: First use `exit();` after `header("location: call_me.php?id=101");`

Comment: what do you expect than AJAX? the header will cause new information return in success function of AJAX (`success: function(msg){ }   `)

Comment: and you have used POST in AJAX but you are getting the `$_GET`

Comment: I don't need any return by the page. Should I remove the success: function(msg){ } ?

Comment: No. what you want to make the browser page refresh by javascript to a page you get from a AJAX response? what do you want?

Comment: On my original code, they are both POST method, I mistyped it in here. See my updates. But I can't still work it out

Comment: I'm here to help you so help me help you by just telling me what do you whant to achieve ?

Comment: @imsiso, actually the real code is to get the access_token return by the facebook graph api that's why I need to reload it.

Comment: OK I mean what you want to reload? the header in a PHP file that is called by AJAX will not cause the browser reload. just cause the out put of the AJAX changes. so if you want to reload the browser you should avoid using AJAX like that and also check @KirenSiva 's answer

Comment: yes, I am considering kirenSiva's answer. Thanks for the help @imsiso

Comment: your welcome.AJAX is a great thing but sometimes we do some misunderstand in it.

Comment: @lvorySantos - I just want to mention you somthing. just be a good supporter and upvote and/or accept his answer if useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

$var = $_GET['id'];

if(empty($var))
{
    // here flag for redirection is set
    echo 1; 
}
else
{
    do something...
}

?>
```

In AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      url: "call_me.php",
      data: "id=" + id,
      success: function(msg){ 
        // checking the response is for redirection     
        if(msg == 1)
            // javascript code for redirecting to callme.php
        window.location = "call_me.php?id=101";
      }                 
});
```

Comment: its better to do return things in JSON format.like `{'status':'fail'}`. and then you can check them like `if(msg.status=='fail'){/*then ...*/}`

Comment: Yes but he is not using any data format. So I think he can work without json. isn't it?

Comment: +1.yes but I just said its better. but when thing get more complicated you should use it.and also when you use JSON you are sure that '1' is not come from `echo ('w'=='w');` ie